# "Trapped for so long" vs. "Trapped so long"

Tags: prepositions

> They had been trapped so long that their first priority was to get medical attention

Is sentence correct or not?

I know 'trapped **for** so long' is very correct, but I wonder if the sentence is acceptable without 'for'.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can omit the preposition **for** with expressions of time-duration.

> We have been waiting (for) ninety minutes.
>
> They lived in London (for) fifteen years.
>
> They were sitting (for) so long in that meeting that they felt stiff when they stood up again.